# Bonita BPM Components

Tags: business-process-management, bonita

I am completely a newbie in Bonita and BPM in general, in my introductory video lessons, I have so far learned about data models, the UI among others. So what I wanted is to know the components, I don't know what they are called but I call them components, I mean contracts, data models, and the likes, what are others that are involved in BPM because I don't even know how to google that.
Any help will be highly appreciated, even a link will be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonita BPM includes three main components:

- Studio: the tool to design your processes. Also include an embedded test environment.
- UI Designer: a web tool included in the Studio that let you create end user web interfaces.
- Portal: the end user web interface to interact with processes. Also used by the administrator to deploy process, configure...
- Engine: the technical component responsible for process execution.

You also have several important concepts in Bonita BPM:

- Process definition: this is the model of the process with tasks, gateway... You create it using Bonita BPM Studio.
- Business Data Model: this is a model of your data that you can create using Bonita BPM Studio. This model will generate a set of Java classes that represents your business data and also associated code to save and retrieve all those data from a database. Data define in this model are shared by all process definitions.
- In a process definition you can declare business variables. They are actually reference to the business data store in the database. You can instantiate them using default value of your business variables. You can update them using operations on tasks.
- Contract define the data expected by the Engine in order to instantiate a process or execute a task. End user will usually submit a form to start a process or execute a task. Contract define which data is expected from the form submission.
- Forms are created using UI Designer. A form is actually a set of widget bind to form variables. The forms variables can be initialized using REST API call or by user input in the widget. REST API call can be done for example to get business variables values or access external system such as a database. Submit button is also associated to a form variable. This form variable must contains all information required by the contract.
- Connectors are part of the process definition and let you interact with third party system when the process is executed. For example it can call a web service to decide if a specific path need to be taken or not.

I would recommend to checkout [getting started tutorial](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/?page=getting-started-tutorial) in the documentation. You can also watch [BPM Camp videos](http://www.bonitasoft.com/for-you-to-read/videos/bpm-camp-bonita-bpm-72).